# Strange database output issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, special-characters

I'm storing program in my database table as it is (I mean no spec. charaacter encoding, etc.. just copying and pasting into db). something like

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vmcmt.h>
...
```

And here is PHP

```
ob_start();
...
fetching information from database and echoing    
$markup = ob_get_clean();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'wrap' => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($markup, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $markup;
```

The problem is, I'm getting oupput code from database half lost. I mean output must be `#include <pthread.h>` getting just  `#include`.

## What I've done

FIrst I thought, maybe it's related with tidy class: turned on debug, and I saw that it's ok with `$markup`. But when I echoed it, got same result. Tried to remove all output buffering functions, tidy.. and just echo content. Still same result. I can't figure out, what am I missing.

Comment: at what point is the html lost? view source and check if one of the tags does not break it. i.e. if the source actually finishes where your output does.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek while echo-ing final output.

Comment: I gathered that, I meant at what point of the output html source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your HTML page source code. `<pthread.h>` is assumed to be a html tag. You need to

```
// Output
echo htmlentities($markup);
```

Comment: lol:))) Now I have no page but html mess.. just markup. nothing visual

Comment: Why is that? More than that, you should display your page in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: you can take a look with teamviewer if you want.

Comment: `echo nl2br(htmlentities($markup));` doesn't it solve the issue with new lines?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15283/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-tim)